# Inserting data in SQLPro

Tags: sequelpro

Is there a way to insert data here, for example, by clicking "Add new row" or double clicking the entry? I'm used to this feature in SequelPro, and it seems a bit crude to not allow a simple GUI way to add in a new row (the reason why I'm using this is so I don't have to manually type in `INSERT` statements:

[image]

Comment: `Tables -> Table_name -> Right Click -> Insert Row`?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda this? https://imgur.com/a/nsp7r0r

Comment: This could be one way. You could remove `LIMIT 100` and check if resultset will allow inline edit.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda it allows editing, but seems very painful adding new rows.

Comment: Many GUI db clients have "painful adding new rows"

Comment: @JacekCz got rid of it and started using Navicat which is quite a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy ways:

1. Right click anywhere in the table, without selecting a certain row. Choose **Add new Row**
2. Right click any row, and choose **Duplicate Row**, this creates a new row with duplicated data, and Null id if you have a primary key. This is not committed to the database until you fix the data that you want. Change what you want and press Enter.

Ta da! You have your data